# Azure RDP problem :cannot connect to remote desktop

Tags: azure, rdp

[image]
please any solution for this error,

- i am using azure portal with  student subscription.
- this error appear after i sign out and try to connect after hours. i tried to create others RDP but the same problem .

i tired to allow :

-the access

check the firewall

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your Account might be Suspended due to some activities !! Check Your Email If there is no issue with Your trial then contact support as they might have limited Your account

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).